# history.back() & history.forward() methods don't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create "Next" and "Back" to go back and forward across my window's history. The problem is that when I click on the "Next" button for the first time it goes to the new URL, however the "Back" button and maybe also the "Next" button don't perform their functions.

I've used `window.history.back()` and `window.history.forward()` methods. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code.

**page1.html**

```js
function right() {
  var total1 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById("rightanswer").checked) {
    total1 += 1;
    console.log(total1);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("score1", total1);
}

function gonext() {
  if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
  } else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
  }
  console.log(sessionStorage.clickcount);
}

if (sessionStorage.clickcount > 1) {
  window.history.forward();
} else if (sessionStorage.clickcount == 1) {
  location.assign("page2.html");
}

//window.history.go(1);
//return false;
```

```html
<b>5+5=</b> <br><br>
<form id="questionform">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" onclick="right()"><span>5</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" onclick="right()" id="rightanswer"><span>10</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" onclick="right()"><span>15</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" onclick="right()"><span>20</span><br>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="&#11013; Back" id="back" form="questionform" disabled>
<input type="submit" value="Next &#10145;" id="next" form="questionform" onclick="gonext()">
```

**page2.html**

```js
function goback() {
  window.history.back()
}

function right() {
  var total2 = Number(localStorage.getItem("score1"));
  if (document.getElementById("rightanswer").checked) {
    total2 += 1;
    console.log(total2);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("score2", total2);
}
```

```html
<b>5+20=</b> <br><br>
<form action="" id="questionform">
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" onclick="right()"><span>10</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" onclick="right()"><span>15</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" onclick="right()"><span>20</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" onclick="right()" id="rightanswer"><span>25</span><br>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="&#11013; Back" id="back" form="questionform" onclick="goback()">
<input type="submit" value="Next &#10145;" id="next" form="questionform" disabled>
```

Comment: You can only go forward if you have gone back, else there is no known location to go forward to

Comment: Also, you need to check if `total2` is a valid number or not. You should use `parseInt( , 10 )` with `isNaN`, otherwise it breaks if there is no `score1` number in `localStorage`.

Comment: The problem is that I can't go back. For the first click on the button "next" the user goes to the new URL (page2.html), but when the user clicks on the button "back" the method `window.history.back()` isn't performed.

Comment: Your buttons should be `type=button` not `type=submit`.